# Why basis of topological space is union of local basis of topological space?

Tags: general-topology, neighbourhood

Let $(X,O)$ be topological space which is defined by  local basis(fundamental neighborhood system)$B_x$ at $x∈X$.
Then, why $∪_{x∈X}B_x$ is basis of $X$, in other words, every open set of $(X,O)$ is written by union of $∪_{x∈X}B_x$?

I think this holds in general topological space, but I have never seen this statement in any my text books or in websites.
Could you tell me the proof of this or reference?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(X,O)$ be a topological space.

- Given $x \in X$, a **local basis at $x$** is a family $\mathcal B_x$ of elements of $O$ with the following two properties:

  - $x$ is in every element of $\mathcal B_x$; and
  - for every $U \in O$ with $x \in U$ there exists $B \in \mathcal B_x$ such that $B \subseteq U$.
- A **basis of $(X,O)$** is a family $\mathcal B$ of elements of $O$ with the following property: For every $U \in O$ and every $x \in U$ there must be exists $B \in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in B \subseteq U$. (Equivalently, $\mathcal B$ is a basis of $(X,O)$ if every element of $O$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal B$.)

> *Claim*: If for any $x \in X$ we have a local basis at $x$, say $\mathcal B_x$, then $\mathcal B := \bigcup_{x \in X} \mathcal B_x$ is a basis of $(X,O)$.

*Proof*: Take $U \in O$ and $x \in U$. By the second property in the definition of local basis we know that there exists $B \in \mathcal B_x$ such that $B \subseteq U$. Now, by the first property in the definition of local basis we know that $x \in B$. Therefore $x \in B \subseteq U$. Since $B \in \mathcal B_x$ says that $B \in \mathcal B$, we have proved the following: For every $U \in O$ and every $x \in U$ there must be exists $B \in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in B \subseteq U$. Hence $\mathcal B$ is a basis of $(X,O)$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

For a set $\mathcal{B}$ to be a basis for a topological space $\left( X, O \right)$, we require the following:

1. The union of all elements of $\mathcal{B}$ should be all of $X$.
2. Given elements $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ with $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, we should be able to find $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$.

It is clear as to why the union of all elements of $\bigcup\limits_{x \in X} B_x$ is all of $X$. Particularly, it is true because each $x \in X$ is contained in every element of $B_x$ and hence together they all cover $X$.

For the second part, we notice that a local base is made of open sets. Therefore, both $B_1$ and $B_2$ are open, and each contains $x$. Using he properties of base, we can find $B_1', B_2' \in B_x$ such that $x \in B_1' \subseteq B_1$ and $x \in B_2' \subseteq B_2$. Consequently, since now both $B_1', B_2' \in B_x$, there is an element $B \in B_x$ such that $x \in B_1' \cap B_2' \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$.

This tells us that the union of all local bases is indeed a base for the topology.

Comment: There's a small typo when x\subset should be x\in B, in the last expression. I still don't see why this " Using he properties of base, we can find B′1,B′2∈Bx such that x∈B′1⊆B1 and x∈B′2⊆B2. " but i´m on it

Comment: @VerónicaR.M.: That is simply because $B_1$ is an open set containing $x$ and $B_x$ is a local base at $x$. Recall the definition of a local base and apply it.

Comment: Your answer only proves that $\mathcal B$ satisfies the conditions for being a basis for *some* topology in $X$, it does not prove that it is a basis for $(X,O)$. See my answer.

Comment: @azif00: You are correct!